# Pantheon Desktop Enviroment not showing in login screen Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: login, pantheon

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 64bit and well I don't like how fresh Ubuntu looks like so I wanted to install Pantheon, installation completed succesfuly but when I reboot and I was in the login screen it only showed Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland, but not Pantheon. How can I solve this? I did the installation with official ElementaryOS PPA repos.

Comment: If you've used the ElementaryOS repositories, then you may be missing a couple of supporting packages. Silly question, but why not simply replace the Ubuntu installation with Elementary OS? This would ensure that everything you need is properly configured right from the very beginning 

Comment: Please add output of `grep -r ^deb.*ppa /etc/apt --include="*.list"` to the question.